# Security of WCF service that allows to read XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, security

I have WCF service that allows users to read XML documents that are stored on server. The signature of that method is the following:

```
XmlNode ReadXmlFile(string path)
```

and also I have

```
bool WriteXmlFile(string path, XMLNode contents)
```

Web service runs under the user that has no admin rights which means It can not read any system settings. I am wondering: given this circumstances is there a way for attacker to break into system? By that I mean change system settings, maybe read any file, not just XML, e.t.c.

Comment: What folder do your users Write to?

Comment: any folder - there is no restriction on that

Comment: That is odd. And where does the folder come from? A service parameter?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is need to allow user to read xml from diffrent path. That's why I was wondering how secure that approach is. As for me it seems quite secure.

Comment: You opened up your entire filesystem for reading and writing... Very unsafe. And that would have taken some overrides on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would rate the security of your existing system as fair but not good. Perhaps not good enough. Ideally all these read and write operations should be performed in a restricted directory only accessible by your wcf service. wcf service can only read and write to this folder. Even the type of files which this process (wcf service) should be restricted. The time window could be restricted as well. It depends how far you want to take it in terms of security.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is check using system.io that it is XML file they are reading and use the environment class to make sure they are not into system or .net folder for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider about XXE Vulnerabilities. If you getting XML input from client then it can be lead to XXE vulnerabilitiy which means attacker can read your local files and so on.

With PHP, you have to disabile entity loader by following codes.

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(true)
```

[https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing)